# ASP.NET MVC return View() hangs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hello everyone I am trying to fix an annoying issue that I am having with ASP.NET MVC.

I have created a new web application and I am noticing that every time I make a change in a .cshtml page, it takes over **15 seconds** to reload the screen with the updated .cshtml page.

I have set a break point on `return View()` and this is where the 15 seconds hang occurs..

Below are images that have the time elapsed on them

[image: My controller with breakpoint image]

[image: Image of Index.cshtml view (here you can see it took 15 seconds to get to this point)]

I have also noticing that within IIS it is stuck in the `ExecuteRequestHandler` stage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using IIS Express or local IIS? I found using the IIS Express would be damn slow. Once I installed IIS and just ran it locally instead it was quick as lightning.

Comment: I have tried both unfortunately and they have the same performance...

Comment: Anything crazy happening in _Layout.cshtml?

Comment: Nope, I have not changed anything in that file.  I have the default code in there.

Comment: Are you using "Individual User Accounts" as in OWIN? If it can't find a local database it might be hanging on that because it can't access it (maybe?). Try running VS as admin

Comment: Thanks for your help Canvas, but unfortunately that did not help either.  I wonder if I need to reinstall ASP.NET because I really have not modified what Visual Studio gave me